# Recreate red & cyan menu item highlight from Persona 5

Tags: unity, graphics

I would like to animate two of my UI images in a similar manner to the red and blue images below:
[image]

I'd like to accomplish this through script, but I'm not certain if it's possible.

Does anyone have insight on how I can recreate this effect? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For color, this is basically an additive blending:

[image]

Unity has made an additive shader for the particle system, for convenience you can use it directly:

[image]

For shapes, this basically draws two quads on the UI and updates their vertex positions via script. Now let's see how to draw polygons on the UI. Here is a simple code. For convenience, I specify that all children of the script transform are the vertices of the polygon, and agree that they are in order.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIPolygon : Graphic
{
    private void OnGUI()
    {
        SetAllDirty();
    }
    protected override void OnPopulateMesh(VertexHelper vh)
    {
        if (transform.childCount < 2)
        {
            return;
        }
        vh.Clear();
        foreach (Transform child in transform)
        {
            vh.AddVert(child.localPosition, color, Vector2.zero);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount - 2; i++)
        {
            vh.AddTriangle(i + 1, i + 2, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, mount this script on a UI object and create 4 children for it:

[image]

Then, create a new material, set its shader to additive, and attach it to the polygon.

Then set the color of this polygon to red, duplicate a polygon and set its color to cyan, and adjust the positions of their vertices:

[image]

Finally, we attach another script to the polygon to make all its children move randomly within a certain range.

**Due to the frame rate of the gif, I don't know whether the movement of the vertices is continuous or discrete. Here I simply let it change the position randomly. You can modify it however you want.

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIPolygonChildrenMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (RectTransform child in transform)
        {
            StartCoroutine(UpdateChildPos(child, child.anchoredPosition));
        }
    }
    IEnumerator UpdateChildPos(RectTransform child, Vector2 prePos)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            child.anchoredPosition = prePos + RandomOffset(30);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
        }
    }
    private Vector2 RandomOffset(float max)
    {
        return new Vector2(Random.Range(-max, max), Random.Range(-max, max));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

And you can add some lerp:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;

public class UIPolygonChildrenMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        foreach (RectTransform child in transform)
        {
            StartCoroutine(UpdateChildPos(child));
        }
    }
    IEnumerator UpdateChildPos(RectTransform child)
    {
        Vector2 prePos = child.anchoredPosition;
        Vector2 fromPos = prePos;
        Vector2 targetPos = prePos + RandomOffset(30);
        float duration = 0.2f;
        float pastTime = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            pastTime += Time.deltaTime;
            if (pastTime >= duration)
            {
                fromPos = targetPos;
                targetPos = prePos + RandomOffset(30);
                pastTime = 0;
            }
            var t = pastTime / duration;
            child.anchoredPosition = Vector2.Lerp(fromPos, targetPos, t);
            yield return null;
        }
    }
    private Vector2 RandomOffset(float max)
    {
        return new Vector2(Random.Range(-max, max), Random.Range(-max, max));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Edit:

Sorry I haven't played Persona 5, I thought the effect would only render on a black background. Now let's try to make it work in any background.

First find the source code of `Mobile/Particles/Additive`. We can see that it simply does an additive blend by `Blend SrcAlpha One`:

```
Shader "Mobile/Particles/Additive" {
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Particle Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    Category {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Blend SrcAlpha One
        Cull Off Lighting Off ZWrite Off Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) }
        
        BindChannels {
            Bind "Color", color
            Bind "Vertex", vertex
            Bind "TexCoord", texcoord
        }
        
        SubShader {
            Pass {
                SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                    combine texture * primary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can use [Stencil](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-Stencil.html) to mark the stencil buffer, indicating that this pixel is rendered by a specific shader, and then the rendered pixel will read this mark and process it. In general, we need to output the normal color and mark it during the first rendering, and then perform additive blend if we read this mark during the second rendering.

```
Shader "Custom/myAdditive" 
{
    Properties {
        _MainTex ("Particle Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }

    Category {
        Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" "IgnoreProjector"="True" "RenderType"="Transparent" }
        Cull Off Lighting Off ZWrite Off Fog { Color (0,0,0,0) }
        
        BindChannels {
            Bind "Color", color
            Bind "Vertex", vertex
            Bind "TexCoord", texcoord
        }
        
        SubShader {
            Pass {
                Stencil 
                {
                    Ref 1
                    Comp NotEqual
                    Pass Replace
                }
                SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                    combine texture * primary
                }
            }
            Pass {
                Stencil {
                    Ref 1
                    Comp Equal
                }
                Blend SrcAlpha One
                SetTexture [_MainTex] {
                    combine texture * primary
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If `ref` Not Equal `1`, Execute the first pass, output the color directly, and set `ref` to `1`. If `ref` Equal `1`, Execute the second pass, output the color after additive blend.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Note that [this effect is sometimes drawn over a white background too](https://66.media.tumblr.com/3d33cd5fb0bb9ea3b26010ef97f5e391/tumblr_okabtjrI7e1t8mwmro4_540.gifv), so it would need a backing or a modified approach to not get washed out in that context.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for taking the time to provide me with such a detailed answer!
It's so cool how you were able to replicate the effect so closely.

Though, I'm not certain if the answer is 1:1 with exactly what I'm trying to do.
Rather than draw two quads, is it possible to do this with the UI shapes I've already created?

I have a text box, and I want to move the brown and the pink shape exactly how you did in the final result of the answer you posted above. Here's an example:

https://i.ibb.co/6R39zfx/image.png

I apologize for not being as specific as I should have been!

Comment: @PayasoPrince I'm afraid it can't. `the UI shapes` are images, We cannot change their vertex positions separately. Maybe they can be used as textures on quad shapes, but just pictures won't accomplish the effect in the answer. : )

Comment: This script inherits from [UI.Graphic](https://docs.unity3d.com/2017.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Graphic.html). `OnPopulateMesh` There is no need to call it manually, it just overloads the parent class method and is called by the engine itself, just like `Start` and `Update`. Color is also a member of the parent class, it will show in inspector. And the [VertexHelper](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.VertexHelper.html) can aid in the generation of meshes for the UI.

Comment: Ah, I see! I'd definitely like to try your idea of using my images as textures on quads.
Would the workflow be exactly the same? In other words, would I still just 1. Mount the UIPolygon and UIPolygonChildrenMove classes on each quad. and 2. create the 4 child game objects for each quad?

Comment: Yes, it should be the same.

Comment: Just following up on this!

Before trying out textures on quads, I tried doing this exactly the way you originally described. The shapes are being created, and the effect is there, but the shapes I'm getting look very different than yours: https://youtu.be/ZV-OXpDRYIQ
I've added both scripts to each polygon, created the children, added the same material.
The only thing I noticed was the console was complaining that the polygons needed a Canvas Renderer. So, I added one to each Polygon. Any idea why I'm not getting the right shape?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142668/discussion-between-payasoprince-and-mangata).